# How to dynamically put contents on react render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that we can use docoment object to create elements dyanamically in the vanilla js
and append that element to some parent element. After doing some research i found this is not the
preferred way to do in react. I need help with this!

h2 element from value of 'data' in ComponentDidMount sould be made and append as a second child to to the div in the render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const data = 'This should be the header 2';

    //h2 element from value of 'data' sould be made and append as a second child to to the div in the render
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='main'>
        <h1>Adding Child Elements</h1>
        {/* This is where the created element should be inserted */}
        <p>This is a second child</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why you didn't dive into [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) first? This is a core react principles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the component's state, add a key `heading` , empty at first , then fill it up when the comopnent mounts :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    heading : "",
    loaded: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = "This should be the header 2";

    this.setState({ heading : data, loaded : true});

    //h2 element from value of 'data' sould be made and append as a second child to to the div in the render
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <h1>Adding Child Elements</h1>
        {/* This is where the created element should be inserted */}
        {this.state.loaded ? <h2>{this.state.heading}</h2>: null }
        <p>This is a second child</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You'll probably want to make the `<h2>` tag conditional as well:

`{ this.state.heading && <h2>{ this.state.heading }</h2> }`

Comment: @Taki i mean how to dynamically put elements inside react render ,i.e after we fetch them form some api. In vanilla js we would do it with appendChild function. What is the proper way to do it in react/

Comment: @DipeshChaulagain in React you don't directly manipulate the DOM and append children, when you fetch data from an API , you put it in the component's state and use conditions to render them, check the updated answer, you're probably looking for : https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html